# Trouble using groupby when combining two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,6,4,4,2,6,7,4,3,2,4,6,1], list('AAABBBBABBBABBA')]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2']

       col1 col2
0     1    A
1     3    A
2     6    A
3     4    B
4     4    B
5     2    B
6     6    B
7     7    A
8     4    B
9     3    B
10    2    B
11    4    A
12    6    B
13    1    B
```

Now what I would like to get is something that looks like this:

```
col1 col2 count
1    A      1
     B      0
2    A      0
     B      2  
etc...
```

I tried to use groupby, but it just doesn't seem to work like intended. Any suggestions? The next step for this would be to get a bar plot from this.

Edit: user 'dm2' has provided me with the correct command: df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts(). If I want to plot this in a bar plot, I get the following: [image]

How do you group this, such that it has A and B joined per number, such that there are two bars next to each other at xtick 1, then two bars together at xtick 2 etc.

Comment: I can't see the link between your current df and what you want to get (i.e. the counts seem off), but groupby seems to work fine. Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Oh maybe I miscounted, I made that output manually. The standard groupby didn't really work, as it just groups everything together.  I believe df.groupby(['col1']).value_counts() didn't help as well, I deleted almost all stuff I had while trying because it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry I just tried that command but that doesn't make sense. I have tried using value_counts() as well but didn't do the job as intended

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem when it's not clear what you tried (which you now clarified in comments) or why what you get is not a suitable output ('doesn't make sense' and 'doesn't seem to work like intended' do not help). It seems like either groupby and count or groupby and value_counts would be great ways to get the counts.

Comment: df.groupby(['col2']).count() returns the correct format that I want in the answer, but that takes into account the whole column, not relating it to the values in col1. This command just returns the total amount of 'a' and 'b' in the column

Comment: I could use this manually with df.loc[(df['col1'] ==number)] everytime, but this quickly gets out of hand

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count()` or `df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts()` ?

Comment: Yes actually! Both work equally well, thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(
    df.pivot_table(
        index="col1",
        columns="col2",
        aggfunc="size",
        fill_value=0,
    ).stack()
)
```

Prints:

```
col1  col2
1     A       1
      B       1
2     A       0
      B       2
3     A       1
      B       1
4     A       1
      B       3
6     A       1
      B       2
7     A       1
      B       0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

*Moving what was accepted in comments here.*

Use both columns in your groupby and one for count aggregate, like:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count()
```

or user one in groupby and one in value_counts, like:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts()
```

If you want to include 0 counts, you can use answer provided by Andrej, or add `.unstack(fill_value = 0).stack()` at the end of either statement, like:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col2'].count().unstack(fill_value = 0).stack()
# or
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value = 0).stack()
```